# Tensorflow calculating incorrect gradients of eigenvalues/vectors w.r.t. underlying matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, gradient-descent

I'm having issues with evaluating the gradients of eigenvalues/eigenvectors with respect to the underlying matrix. Tensorflow evaluates the gradients, however these are not consistent with analytical derivations.

We are using tf.self_adjoint_eig to evaluate the spectral decomposition for the tensorflow variable input. We have initialised this with a symmetric matrix to satisfy the self adjoint operator property. We wish to take the derivative of individual eigenvalues or eigenvector with respect to the original matrix (note for eigenvectors we take one element from one eigenvector, e.g. element 2 in eigenvector 1 to avoid the issue of gradient aggregation for now).

The methodology for evaluating analytical gradients of eigenvalues and vectors of a symmetric real matrix can be found in the paper "On differentiating Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors" by Magnus (1985), Theorem 1 eqn (6) + (7). We evaluated using our input matrix the gradients under this paper and compared it to tensorflow evaluated gradients and the gradients from finite difference approximation. For the eigenvalues, the gradients are similar (identical on diagonal entries, off by a factor of 2 on off-diagonal elements), however the eigenvectors are off by quite a bit outside the diagonal entries. To start, define a matrix A (any suggestions on presenting matrices in posts would be helpful!)

A =

- -3 -2 4
- -2 1 1
- 4 1 5

using np.linalg.eig and tf.self_adjoint_eig on A (I simply initialised a variable with A and computed the gradient for the tf implementation)

Tensorflow eigenvalues: [-5.43071561 1.76904987 6.66166575]
Python eigenvalues: [-5.43071561 6.66166575 1.76904987]

I now wish to evaluate the gradient of eigenvalue 1 (-5.43071561) w.r.t. A.

Analytical gradient (Magnus 1985):

- 0.75896178  0.28555906 -0.31842553
- 0.28555906  0.10744148 -0.11980748
- -0.31842553 -0.11980748  0.13359674

Tensorflow gradient:

- 0.75896178    0           0
- 0.57111812,   0.10744148  0
- -0.63685107  -0.23961495  0.13359674

The diagonal entries are the same but the off-diagonal entries are clearly off by a factor of 2. Now we try and evaluate gradients for the eigenvectors.

Tensorflow eigenvectors:

- -0.87118413 -0.31452619 -0.37697678
- -0.32778267 0.94426587 -0.0303395
- 0.36550888 0.09713517 -0.92572567

Python eigenvectors:

- 0.87118413  0.37697678 -0.31452619
- 0.32778267  0.0303395  0.94426587
- -0.36550888 0.92572567 0.09713517

We try and find the gradient of the eigenvector 1 element 2 (+/-0.32778267). We expect the tensorflow gradient to the equivalent to the analytical gradient (after taking into account the sign difference).

Analytical gradient:

- 0.03511309 -0.10795607 -0.01312188
- 0.01321128 -0.04061843 -0.0049371
- 0.01473184 0.04529341 0.00550534

Tensorflow gradient:

- -0.03511309, 0. , 0.
- 0.09474478, 0.04061843, 0.
- 0.02785372, -0.04035631, -0.00550534

Besides the entries being different on the off-diagonal, one issue is that tensorflow only returns the lower triangle of the gradient. Despite A being symmetric, the contribution to the gradient is not symmetric as shown in the analytical evaluation above. Thank you for reading!

TL:DR, I think the gradient computations are done incorrectly. Any thoughts or similar experiences?

Code to reproduce below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
from numpy.linalg import pinv

#create upper triangular matrix
A_vec = np.array([-3,-2,4,-2,1,1,4,1,5])
A = np.reshape(A_vec,[3,3])
e = eig(A)
#extract eigenvalues and eigenvectors
e_val = e[0]
e_vec = e[1]

#tensorflow variables
A_tf = tf.Variable(tf.constant(A,dtype=tf.float64))
e_tf = tf.self_adjoint_eig(A_tf)
#extract eigenvalues and eigenvectors
e_val_tf = e_tf[0]
e_vec_tf = e_tf[1]

#initialise variables and run session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#print A
print("A:")
print(A)

#show eigenvalues for Tensorflow and R
print("Tensorflow eigenvalues:",sess.run(e_val_tf))
print("Python eigenvalues:",e_val)


############# Eigenvector element gradient #############

eval_grad_tf = tf.gradients(e_val_tf[0], A_tf) #Tensorflow gradient of first eigenvalue w.r.t. A

#analytical gradient
eigenvec = e_vec[:,0]

#analytical deriv from analytical gradient of eigenvalue from Magnus (1985), "On differentiating
#Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors", Theorem 1 eqn (6)
eval_grad_analytical = np.outer(eigenvec,eigenvec)

print("Analytical gradient:")
print(eval_grad_analytical)
print("Tensorflow gradient:")
print(sess.run(eval_grad_tf))


############# Eigenvector element gradient #############

print("Tensorflow eigenvectors:")
print(sess.run(e_vec_tf))
print("Python eigenvectors:")
print(e_vec)

#tensorflow gradient
evec_grad_tf = tf.gradients(e_vec_tf[1,0], A_tf)

#analytical gradient

#analytical deriv from analytical gradient of eigenvalue from Magnus (1985), "On differentiating
#Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors", Theorem 1 eqn (7)

evec_grad_analytical = np.kron(eigenvec, pinv(e_val[0]*np.eye(3)-A)) #calculates derivatives for each component of eigenvector 3
evec_grad_analytical1 = np.reshape(evec_grad_analytical[1,:],[3,3]) #retrieves column 2 which should correspond to the gradient of eigenvector 3 element 2 w.r.t. A

print("Analytical gradient:")
print(evec_grad_analytical1)
print("Tensorflow gradient:")
print(sess.run(evec_grad_tf))
```